# "Managed by CM" What meaning of CM

Tags: java, maven

I have read basic maven from http://webdev.apl.jhu.edu/~jcs/ejava-javaee/coursedocs/605-784-site/docs/content/html/devenv-mavenbasics.html

and found

1.1.1. Source Tree managed by CM

1.1.2. Build Tree not managed by CM

What "CM" meaning?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Is this from a class?  Why don't you ask your teacher?

Comment: Hi @tieTYT, I'm googling basic maven and found this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is usually short for SCM which is [Software Configuration Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management). SCM encompasses various parts of project management.

However in this context 'CM' (I'm inferring from its use in the linked document) is likely referring to a [Version Control System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) (VCS) such as CVS, SVN, HG, or GIT.

The confusion is probably because there is an alternate definition of SCM that means 'Source Control Management' which is equivalent, as opposed to a superset of, VCS. Personally I dislike the use of this as it is easily confused with Software Configuration Management.

Comment: To expand upon this answer, and what the page OP linked to is saying: you wouldn't want to check your build tree into a version control tool because (among many other reasons) it typically includes binary files that cannot be properly version controlled.